# Как в wordpress получить title страницы без использования yoast?

Tags: php, wordpress

Страница в wordprese имеет название "Шоколад аленка", но при использовании плагина yoast  title будет уже модифицирован - Купить "**Шоколад аленка**" в магазине...

Подскажите какой будет код в php первоначального title и первоначального title с использованием шорткода именно оригинальной страницы. Как правило он идет на странице в .

Использовал код в function.php

```
function my_shortcode_fn() {
        global $post;
  return wp_title('', false); // если речь о title страницы
        return get_the_title($post->ID); // если речь о заголовке поста
}
add_shortcode( 'myshortcode', 'my_shortcode_fn' );
```

но он выводит уже модифицированный title страницы.
Заранее всем благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать такой шорткод:

```
function my_shortcode_fn() {
  global $post;
  $post = get_post($post);
  return $post->post_title;
}
add_shortcode( 'original_title', 'my_shortcode_fn' );
```

И использовать `[original_title]` для вывода первоначального title страницы.

P.S. Вряд-ли Yoast SEO меняет сам заголовок. На моей памяти там нет ничего, что меняет фильтры `wp_title` или `the_title`. Думаю проблему нужно искать в другом плагине, посмотрите по плагинам/теме где используется `add_filter("the_title" ...`